# Reftex and \include*{sections/sec} - how to get it to work?

Tags: labels, include, reftex

I have a multi-file LaTeX project with statements like `\include*{sections/sec1}`. Reftex does not find the labels defined in the included files. When switching to the unstarred variant `\include{sections/sec1}`, the labels are found just fine.

I have added the starred variant in

```
 '(reftex-include-file-commands (quote ("include" "input" "include*")))
```

but that does not help. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question as `\include*`  is not defined by default. Might be better to ask how to get revtex to support user defined macros. I think I gave up last time I played with it, and just locallt redefined include/input

Comment: I presume you've used the custom interface to tweak the variable.  Can you change your addition to `include\\*`, save it, restart Emacs and try it again?

Comment: @ArashEsbati : That solved the problem, thanks a lot.

Edit: Hint: When adding `include\\*` via the user interface, the ` \ ` got duplicated, so in `.emacs` I ended up with `include\\\\*`. This of course did not work. Hence, when using the interface to change the variable, just `include\*` might be enough.

Comment: Yes, my bad, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RefTeX generates a regexp from the entries in `reftex-include-file-commands` and then parses the document.  `*` has a special meaning in regexp; in order to match a literal asterisk, you have to quote it.  When using Emacs' custom interface to tweak the variable, add your entry as `include\*` instead of `include*`.  When setting this variable in your init file directly, then do:

```lisp
(setq reftex-include-file-commands '("include" "input" "include\\*")
```

or:

```lisp
(setq reftex-include-file-commands '("include\\*?" "input")
```